# Generating XSLT for the given XML. Error: Mismatch

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I Have an XML something like this

```
<NavigatorItems>
  <Navigator Name="Product">
    <ModifierName>Product1</ModifierName>
    <ModifierLink>www.Product1.com</ModifierLink>
    <ModifierName>Product2</ModifierName>
    <ModifierLink>www.Product2.com</ModifierLink>
    <ShowAll>www.ProductMain.com</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>

  <Navigator Name="Article">
    <ModifierName>Article1</ModifierName>
    <ModifierLink>www.Article1.com</ModifierLink>
    <ModifierName>Article2</ModifierName>
    <ModifierLink>www.Article2.com</ModifierLink>
    <ShowAll>www.ArticleMain.com</ShowAll>
  </Navigator>
</NavigatorItems>
```

I Need to show something like this:

[image]

I tried the following XSLT but it throws some error (mismatch):
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: `</ModifierName>`

My Code:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="NavigatorItems/Navigator">
  <xsl:variable name="link" select="ModifierLink"/>
  <tr>
    <td><a href ="{$link}"><xsl:value-of select="ModifierName"/></td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:test select="ShowAll"> 
  <xsl:variable name="linkShowAll" select="ShowAll"/>
     <tr> <td> <a href="{$linkShowAll}"> View More Results <td> </tr>
  </xsl:test>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Where Am I going wrong ? Please Suggest...

Comment: Please be more precise about the error you get. "some error" is hardly useful. Also, the XML you show is syntactically invalid. Provide your real XML or put more attention to your mock-ups.

Comment: hi Tomalak.. thanks for the reply.. its: XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </ModifierName>

Comment: As I said, your "XML" is syntactically invalid. If that's *really* what you're trying to work with, slap the person who created this mess. ;)

Comment: Haha :) Actually this is getting generated from a response. Can you suggest me how the XML can be framed in this case? As I need to show the top 3 products/articles along with "view more" which is only a single link. Can it be added in the attribute of Navigator tag ? But I'm not sure whether we can add the href link like string as attribute.

Comment: From what response is it created? Obviously that server has no concept of XML, so this should be fixed in the first instance. Only after the server delivers *actual* XML (instead of something that remotely looks like XML) your other problem can be solved.

Comment: Any suggestions for the XML ?

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of problems with your code. I think I've fixed them all, but let me know if you have any problems with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="NavigatorItems/Navigator">   
            <xsl:variable name="link" select="ModifierLink"/>   
            <tr>   
                <td>
                    <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="ModifierLink"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="ModifierName" /></a>                                       
                </td>   
            </tr>   
            <xsl:if test select="ShowAll != ''">    
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="ShowAll"/>View More Results</a>                                       
                    </td>   
                </tr>   
            </xsl:test>   
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```